# Closed Form Solution of equation

Tags: geometry

I am trying to solve for the intersection of 2 ellipses. I start by equating the 2 formulas together:

$$ (\frac {x-h_1}{a_1})^2 + (\frac {y-k_1}{b_1})^2 = (\frac {x-h_2}{a_2})^2 + (\frac {y-k_2}{b_2})^2    $$

I rearrange the $x$ and $y$ to different sides and complete the square. Eventually I get a form of:

$$ k_1(y+k_2)^2 + k_2 = k_3(x+k_4)^2 + k_5  $$

Apparently this cannot be solved to get a value, so my question is how do I go on from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

In fact, you have two equations $$(\frac {x-h_1}{a_1})^2 + (\frac {y-k_1}{b_1})^2 =1$$ $$(\frac {x-h_2}{a_2})^2 + (\frac {y-k_2}{b_2})^2=1$$ Extract $y$ from each equation as a function of $x$ and make them equal. This would give you one equation in $x$ (not simple); solve it and go back to $y$. There could be multiple solutions.